# Domain User logged in with Temp Profile in Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain

I am new to the forum. I am having a trouble with Windows server 2008 R2 Domain. I am having IBM 3650 Server installed with Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit domain. I am using Thin Clients as Nodes. Model No of thin client is : NComputing L300. Now I have created Domain users. All the thin Client are successfully connected to the server over the LAN and ask to provide the user log in details i.e. credentials. Now if I login using one of the user and then Go to "c"\Users\" folder what I can see is a "Temp.domainname" folder is created as profile folder instead of the "username" profile. Due to this every time the user logs off, the "temp.domainname" profile is deleted automatically. This is happening with all the users.

More over I tried log in using the uers credentials locally in server it self in order to assure that is related to thin client or some thing is wrong with the server. But even if I login locally in the server using the user credential, it loads with "Temp.domainname" profile instead of the "username" profile.

Can you please let me know how can I get out of this?

Answer (score 5):

This happens a lot when you have Mandatory Profiles configured for Server 2003 and then move to 2008+ without planning. Profiles are different between these versions of Windows, so a mandatory 2003/XP profile won't load on Vista+/2008+, which will cause a temporary profile to load.

My hunch is that you just have misconfigured profiles.

If you don't, it could also be caused by disk corruption or some other oddity. Check the event logs for more descriptive details and update your question if this doesn't resolve it.

Comment: I will just sent you the screenshot of the event log. As far as the migration part is concern, I have not migrated the server from 2003 to 2008. Instead it is a fresh installation of Win 2008 Standard Edition R2 with 5 nos. of SAS HDD. First 2 in RAID 1 and the rest as RAID 5. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

A Fix I have found for this is logging into the server as an admin, deleted the registry keys in regedit for the users that are logging in with a temp account.

The registry key can be found in the program called regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

When you have done this also create a back up of the users files, rename the users fold to *username*.old.

Log in as the user, this should then mean they are logging in with a clean profile i.e. no documents or settings.

By which point log off as the user, copy all the files from the *username*.old into the newly created user folder, check there is a new registry key for that user, then log back in.

I am yet to find out why this is happening but by recreating the profile I have not had this problem again.

Regards,
Alex Hawkins

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making a back up copy of the profile to another disk.  Then restarting the machine into Safe Mode.  I got into System properties and removed all profiles.  Then restarted and logged in with my domain account.
Then it worked.